# What's wrong with this sentence? How can it be improved?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, tenses, sentence

> It has been a long time that I associated myself with an organisation.

I'm not sure if I can use *myself* in this context, since there is an *I* already implying the same. Can I use *associated* - a past tense here?

Any better way to convey the same?

Comment: "long time" ... "since" (not "that"); "... I associated with an organization" works.

Comment: "How can it be **improved**?" -- not 'improvised'.

Comment: Is it "It has been a long time since I associated with an organization" ?

Comment: I thought there was a ban on preformat being applied inline to a single word, that they should use italicization instead. Is the ban still in effect?

Comment: You can use the past tense because you're talking about associating in the past.

Comment: What are you trying to say? That you associated in the past, but haven't been associated since then? Or that you associated a long time ago and are still associated now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to say. If you used to be associated with an organization, but have not been for a long time, it's

> It's been a long time since I associated with an organization.

If you mean that you associated with an organization a long time ago, and are still associated now, you write:

> It's been a long time that I've been associated with an organization.

or more commonly:

> I've been associated with an organization for a long time.